# Find closest date from array of objects to given date

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, date, time

I have a JSON file that contains objects of dates in the "dd/mm/yyyy" format.
I'd like to find the day closest to today using Javascript. I have already figured out how to get the current date in the respective format but now I'm struggling to find a way to get the closest one. I'd appreciate any help, so far I'm always getting the very first item whatever I try (I haven't found anything that works for me here).
Example JSON:

```
[
  {
  "match": "Liverpool - Chelsea",
  "league": "PL",
  "date": "20/06/2021",
  "venue": "Liverpool"
  },
  {
  "match": "Manchester - Arsenal",
  "league": "PL",
  "date": "15/08/2021",
  "venue": "Manchester"
  }
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by the closest day?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Whatever day of those in the file is closest to today

Comment: Give an json object example and say what and how you need your result

Comment: What's the specific issue? My take is that if you can get the day diff it's a normal iterate/keep-closest, the only thing you'd need to decide is how to handle equal diffs.

Comment: Try converting the strings into dates? They can be subtracted from today's date, comparing which one is smaller.

Comment: I assume you already know about dates.compare(a,b) returns 1, 0 -1

Comment: @DaveNewton How do I get that diff though? Just substracting the days and today? Sorry, if it's obvious I'm only a beginner.

Comment: That should be (relatively) easy to search for, e.g., "js compare dates ignore time" or something like that :)

Comment: @DaveNewton so I compare all the dates such that I only have e.g. the future ones and then I compare these in order to find out the one that is less than all the others?

Comment: @Alex The order doesn't matter. You don't state what "closest" means, e.g., yesterday is "closer" to today than four days from now, so you need to decide if before/after matters. Otherwise "closeness" is the absolute value of the difference in days; just track which date (or object containing the date) is the closest--same way you could find the min or max in a list with a single iteration.

Comment: @DaveNewton I totally get that but I'm struggling with the technique to find out how much time lactually lays between the dates - e.g. 10 days between 10/06/2021 and 20/06/2021 - in order to identify the minimum. Sorry if I didn't make myself plain so far.

Comment: @Alex I still think that searching for something like "js number of days between dates" would be helpful, and there are a couple of answers below that appear to work, although I haven't tested them, just ran the snippets.

Comment: @DaveNewton Ok thank you very much for your effort, I think I now have an idea how to do it

Comment: @Alex are you trying to achieve it by yourself without looking at the answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to find the closest date to now, you should reduce your items.

While reducing, you should know how to access the date field and how to parse it. If the distance between the current (`curr`) and the `target` it less than the previous (`prev`), update the accumulator (`prev`) to be the current (`curr`).

```js
const findClosest = (data, accessor, target = Date.now()) =>
  data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const a = Math.abs(accessor(curr).getTime() - target);
    const b = Math.abs(accessor(prev).getTime() - target);
    return a - b < 0 ? curr : prev;
  });

const sampleData = [
  { "name": "A", "date": "31/12/2000" },
  { "name": "B", "date": "31/12/2010" },
  { "name": "C", "date": "31/12/2100" }
];

const processDateString = (dateString) => {
  const [ date, month, year ] = dateString.split(/\//g).map(Number);
  return new Date(year, month - 1, date);
};

const closest = findClosest(sampleData, ({ date }) => processDateString(date));

console.log(closest);
```

Comment: When parsing the timestamp to a Date, there is no need to map the values to Number, and if there was, `map(Number)` is sufficient. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl thank you very much for your help, it's working perfectly for me. Just for better understanding: what does `/\//g` do in this context and why do I have to calculate month - 1?

Comment: @Alex when you construct a `Date`, the month is indexed starting at 0; so January is 0.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl ah right forgot about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the dates with a regex, then sort the dates and retrieve the first one like this:

```js
const dates = [
  {
    match: "Liverpool - Chelsea",
    league: "PL",
    date: "20/06/2021",
    venue: "Liverpool",
  },
  {
    match: "Manchester - Arsenal",
    league: "PL",
    date: "15/08/2021",
    venue: "Manchester",
  },
];
 
const parseDate = date => new Date(date.replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/g, '$2/$1/$3'));

const diff = (date, now) => Math.abs(parseDate(date) - now);

const comparator = now => ({ date: date1 }, { date: date2 }) => diff(date1, now) - diff(date2, now);

const [closest] = dates.sort(comparator(new Date));

console.log(closest);
```